# JDBC executeBatch strange behaviour

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to execute a callablestatement on a stored procedure (not function - but procedure) on Postgresql 11.

I create a batch ready for execution like this:

```
int[] results;
final int batchsize = 1000;

CallableStatement Stmt = null;

final int batchsize = 1000;

String execString = "{call insertnewrecall(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
Stmt = conn.prepareCall(execString);

        for (RecallType recall : recallList) {

            Stmt.setInt(1, recall.getReportid());
            Stmt.setInt(2, recall.getInternalid());
            Stmt.setString(3, recall.getPatsurname());
            Stmt.setString(4, recall.getPatfirstname());
            Stmt.setString(5, recall.getPatdob());
            Stmt.setString(6, recall.getPatmobile());
            Stmt.setString(7, recall.getPatemail());
            Stmt.setString(8, recall.getDrfirstname());
            Stmt.setString(9, recall.getDrsurname());
            Stmt.setString(10, recall.getTestname());
            Stmt.setString(11, recall.getCheckdate());
            Stmt.setString(12, recall.getSource());
            Stmt.setString(13, recall.getRecalltype());


            Stmt.addBatch();

            if(++count % batchsize == 0){
                results = Stmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }


        results = Stmt.executeBatch();
```

The stored procedure is:

```
create or replace procedure insertnewrecall(
                                                    in p_reportid       int,
                                                    IN p_internalid     int,
                                                    IN p_patsurname     varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_patfirstname   varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_patdob         varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_patmobile      varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_patemail       varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_drfirstname    varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_drsurname      varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_testname       varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_checkdate      varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_source         varchar(100),
                                                    IN p_recalltype     varchar(100)) 
as $$
declare lv_checkdate recallqueue.checkdate%type;
begin 
.....
```

I can call and insert new rows on the command line and it seems to work quite well, with data being entered into the table

When I try to call the procedure via the Postgresql JDBC driver (version 42.2.5), it keeps throwing an error:

```
SQLException: Batch entry 0 select * from insertnewrecall
 Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
```

To me, it seems as though the JDBC driver is trying to execute the stored procedure through a 'SELECT" statement, which would be consistent with the execution of a function (based on my reading of the postgresql online documentation) but rather it should be issuing a "CALL" statement, even though my CallableStatement string has "{call insertnewrecall( ?,?...}"

I'm going nuts here trying to work out if its me, or the current JDBC driver has not been updated to account for the ability to call a procedure now rather than a function.

Has any one had any experience with this and can shed some light, or point me to some documentation that I am yet to read?

Cheers

Comment: OK, I'm as confused AF. I stumbled across (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvcscsp.html) and was looking at their call statement:

cstmt = con.prepareCall("CALL DSN8.DSN8ED2(?,?,?,?,?)");

I was under the impression that the call statement needed to be look like:
cstmt = con.prepareCall("{CALL DSN8.DSN8ED2(?,?,?,?,?)}"); -- note the curly braces.

Needless to say, the statement WITHOUT the curly braces works perfectly. Can someone tell me what the difference is?

Many thanks

Comment: The one with curly braces is a JDBC escape that the driver translates to database specific format, and the other is directly sent to the server without translation.

Comment: Thanks MarkRotteveel. I had no idea that was the case! Many thanks!!